# Run from eclipse IDE works fine but terminates when run from terminal

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using eclipse CDT in linux. I have a code that uses threads, TCP, files etc. This program runs fine in the Eclipse IDE but when I try to run this from the linux terminal, the program gets terminated in between. There is no error message shown. Can someone help me?

Comment: maybe if you post some code? have you tried debugging? backtracing with gdb would be a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem I was facing. One of my thread was trying to send through TCP before connection. I still don't know why it had no issues while running in IDE. Now it works fine after i modified my code to use TCP only after connection has been established.